# Condition number for matrix of eigenvectors of a diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, norms, numerical-linear-algebra, eigenvector, matrix-inverse

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable matrix, i.e., $A=SDS^{−1}$. For any matrix $A$, condition number is defined as $\kappa(A)=\|A\| \|A\|^{-1}$.
For $A$ being a diagonalizable matrix, define $G_A=\{{S: S^{-1} A S=D }\}$, then $K(A)=\min_{G_A}\{{\|S\| \|S^{-1}\|}\}$ is called the spectral condition number of A. Can we bound the spectral condition number $K(A)$ of any diagonalizable matrix A?

Answer (score 4):

See: [An upper bound for the spectral condition number of a diagonalizable matrix](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82623683.pdf) (1997)

Comment: I have read this paper. But unfortunately, this bound looks too relaxed. The bound is exponential on the order of the matrix.

Comment: this may well be the best you can do without further info on the matrix; if the matrix is diagonally dominant, you can do better, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3520012/87355

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3520012/87355 handles the condition number, not the spectral condition number. How can one obtain a bound on $K(A)$ from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3520012/87355 knowing that $A$ is diagonally dominant? (Actually I'm also interested in the case where $A$ is tridiagonal)